# Find all timings with given angle of clock minute and hour hands

Tags: java, c++, algorithm

Given absolute value of angle between hour and minute hands.
We need to find all valid values of time (in hours and minutes, both non-negative integers) from midnight (inclusive) to noon (not inclusive) which satisfy the given angle.

It is to be noticed that time value is considered valid if the angle between the clock's hands for that value and the angle given has described differ by less than 1/120 degrees.
Also, the movement of the minute hand influences the hour hand. That is, every minute, it moves by 1/60th of the angular distance between two consecutive hour marks.

So how to solve this problem in good way. I wrote down a code with hell lot of if and else. So just wondering if there is clean way of finding all of them.

Example : If A=30 then it can be :

```
01:00
11:00
```

Comment: So, what have you done so far? What's your approach?

Comment: @LorenzoBelli Ok My approach is that as every minute, it moves by 1/60th of the angular distance between two consecutive hour marks and we should have error of less than 1/120. so keeping it at worst case lets assume 1/120. so we need to check for each of 2 minutes. If we have A degree as angle

Comment: paste some sample code

Comment: Do you assume that the hour hand must point directly at the hour number or does it move between the numbers like a traditional analogue clock? This affects whether 12:05 and 11:55 would also be valid at A=30?

Comment: I would make the minute hand make step of 1 minute. At each step you determine the two possible position for the hour hand (=minute hand +A and minute hand -a) then check if that position if valid. O(60x2)

Comment: @LorenzoBelli How ? Please elaborate

Comment: @William_Wilson You are wrong. THEY ARE NOT AT 30 DEGREES WITH 12:05 and 11:55

Comment: That's why I asked if the assumption was that the hour hand points to the hour directly. If the hour hand moves it drastically affects the times that represent the angle. 11:00 and 1:00 only work at exactly 5 minutes BECAUSE the hour hand is pointed at the hour, but this will not be the case for any other minute value. The algorithm could be brute forced with a couple of loops. Show an attempt in code and we can guide you to the solution.

Answer (score 1):

I'll try an idea in pseudocode

```
for minuteHand in [0,59]:
    minuteAngle=angle(minuteHand) // gives the angle respect to the 0
    hourAngle1 = minuteAngle+A //Should be modified to account for the precision
    hourAngle2 = minuteAngle-A
    if isValidTime(minuteAngle,hourAngle1): // check if the two hands express a valid time at this angle
        found a valid time
    if isValidTime(minuteAngle,hourAngle2):
        found a valid time
```

Answer (score 1):

Problem of currently going on competition in Codechef.

https://www.codechef.com/OCT15/problems/TIMEASR

Answer (score 0):

I do not really understand what is your problem. "How to solve this?" is a bit to vague to give a short answer. However, the first thing I would do is to convert all values to the same units. 30 degrees corresponds to 1/12th of the full circle, ie in one minute one hand moves by 6 degrees (1/60 of a full turn) and the other one by 1/2 degree (30 degrees in a full hour). So you are basically trying to solve

```
abs( (t * 6) - (t*1/2) ) == 30 + n*360
```

where `n = 0,1,2,....` That modulo part makes it a bit tedious to get a direct solution, but you can simply run a loop for any values of `t` to find the solutions. Hope this helps. If not, maybe you should consider showing some of your code....

Comment: ps: `t` is the time since `0:00` in minutes. To get the time in `hh:mm` format you would have to convert it once you have the solutions for `t`

Answer (score 0):

This question shouldn't be answered right now as it's from a LOng contest being hosted by codechef. So , this is spoiling the problem for enthusiasts like us who wants to solve this on our own.